# Por que a minha view não está apresentando o design do css?

Tags: css, laravel

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Controle de estoque</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Listagem de Produtos</h1>
  <table class="table">
  <?php foreach($produtos as $p): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $p->nome ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->valor ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->descricao ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->quantidade ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach ?>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque o caminho está errado. Se você está usando os arquivos de `css` na pasta public (que é o recomendado) deverá adicionar da seguinte forma:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você não esteja apresentado o caminho correto para o arquivo.
tente isso.

```html
<link href="../css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

é sempre bom limpar o cache do navegador também :)

Comment: não resolveu. Eu estou usando o laravel 5.5, e parece que ele não vem instalado algumas coisas, será que é por isso?